# Meteor: ReferenceError: Accounts is not defined

Tags: meteor

I just finished developing a Meteor package. Now I want to test it by adding it to a new Meteor app:

**my_cool_package_name/package.js**

```
Package.on_use(function(api){
    api.use("accounts-password@1.1.1");
});
```

**Add my_cool_package_name to a new project**

```
meteor add my_cool_package_name

Changes to your project's package version selections:

    accounts-base          added, version 1.2.0
    accounts-password      added, version 1.1.1
```

**List installed packages**

```
meteor list

    meteor-platform      1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in your app
    my_cool_package_name  1.0.0+ This is my_cool_package_name
```

**Start meteor**

```
meteor

ReferenceError: Accounts is not defined

W20150817-15:30:49.707(-4)? (STDERR)     at manage_users_log.insert.username (app/server/fixtures.js:7:17)
W20150817-15:30:49.707(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150817-15:30:49.707(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105:1)
W20150817-15:30:49.708(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/fixtures.js:6:4
W20150817-15:30:49.708(-4)? (STDERR)     at app/server/fixtures.js:36:3
W20150817-15:30:49.708(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/Documents/meteor/my_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150817-15:30:49.708(-4)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150817-15:30:49.708(-4)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/me/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.1kp2n64++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150817-15:30:49.708(-4)? (STDERR)     at /Users/me/Documents/meteor/my_app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

**server/fixtures.js**

```
if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
    var users = [
        {username:'admin',email:'admin@example.com',password:'adminadmin',roles:['admin'],status:'enabled',profile:{first_name:'admin',last_name:'admin'}},
        {username:'user',email:'user@example.com',password:'useruser',roles:['user'],status:'enabled',profile:{first_name:'user',last_name:'user'}}
    ];
    _.each(users, function(user){
        var user_id = Accounts.createUser({
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password,
            profile: {
                first_name: user.profile.first_name,
                last_name: user.profile.last_name,
            }
        });
        Meteor.users.update(
            {_id: user_id},
            {$set: 
                {
                    roles: user.roles,
                    status: user.status
                }
            }
        );
    });
}

if (manage_users_log.find().count() === 0) {
    manage_users_log.insert({
        username: "admin",
        category: "server_startup",
        description: "Meteor server started."
    });
}
```

If it helps, the app structure is laid out like so:

```
client
    my_app.html
packages
    my_cool_package_name
server
    fixtures.js
```

Comment: The rest of the error would be really helpful here. Is the error coming from a file inside of the package or somewhere else? I'll bet it's the latter.

Comment: It may also help looking at the source of the initial page to see in what order the files are actually loaded. Can you make sure that you custom package is indeed loaded after "accounts-base"?

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question to include more details about the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `api.imply` to give your app access to the exported symbols of your package dependencies.

```
Package.onUse(function(api){
  api.use("accounts-password@1.1.1");
  //
  api.imply("accounts-password@1.1.1");
});
```

When you add a package depending on other packages, their exported symbols are not available to the main app, you need to imply them to make this happen.