# Meteor-stubs spyOn Accounts not working when testing package

Tags: unit-testing, testing, meteor, meteor-velocity

I am facing a weird behavior and I hope you could help me on it.

I am testing my package using sanjo:jasmine@0.20.2 and velocity:meteor-stubs@1.1.0'
In my tests I do:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    MeteorStubs.install();
});
```

Works well for Meteor.users.

But when using spyOn on Accounts it doesn't work.
If I do this in my test method:

```
spyOn(Accounts, 'setPassword').and.callFake(function() {
  // do nothing
});
var result = MyService.changePassword(user, newPassword);
expect(Accounts.setPassword).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

html-reporter reports:

```
Expected spy setPassword to have been called.
```

Any idea ?
Thanks for your help.
Yann

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved the issue.

Thanks to stackoverflow [Meteor: ReferenceError: Accounts is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058367/meteor-referenceerror-accounts-is-not-defined)

> Use `api.imply` to give your app access to the exported symbols of
>   your package dependencies.

I have added it in my package.js file:

```
api.imply([
    'accounts-password'
  ]);
```

See full exchange here:
https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-stubs-spyon-accounts-not-working-when-testing-package/11109/9